# Magnetic field on the surface of a solenoid

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields

> Given an infinite dielectric cylinder of radius $r$, with uniform surface charge density $\sigma$, rotating about its axis with a constant angular velocity $\omega$, find the magnitude of magnetic field on its surface.

I understand that this rotating cylinder behaves like a solenoid, and we can thus compute that the external magnetic field is $0$, and that the magnetic field inside it is a constant value (which we can find using Ampere's Law). But what is the magnetic field *at* the surface?

Do we sort of assume that an Amperian loop slices all the charges in half? Because the answer to a follow-up question asking for the *pressure* on the surface due to magnetic forces seemed to suggest a value that was half the field inside the cylinder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right: in surface modeling, the field is discontinuous and one cannot speak of the field “on the surface”.

For the following, the factor ½ comes from the fact that we distinguish the field created by an elementary surface $dS$ on which we seek the force and the field created by the rest of the solenoid: we can show that in the solenoid, the two are equal (and they are opposite on the outside of the solenoid)

Comment: Thanks for the help!